# git change local ref

Tags: git, version-control

I was working on my local branch `feature-branch`. I made commits and pushed my local branch to remote. I did `git status` and it showed

```
Your branch is 6 commits ahead of origin/master
```

After that I switch to another branch with `git checkout another_branch`. After working on this branch, I had to go back to my feature branch and I did that by `git checkout feature_branch`

After this I did `git status` and it showed

```
Your branch is up to date with origin/feature_branch
```

Earlier it was comparing `feature_branch` with `origin/master`. But now it is comparing with itself. How do I change it to compare with `origin/master` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git status` command does a bunch of useful things.  One of them is to compare the current branch's tip with the tip of its *upstream* branch.

You say that at one point, you were on branch `feature-branch`, and `git status` compared that to `origin/master`.  So this means that the upstream setting for `feature-branch` was `origin/master`, as if you had run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master feature-branch
```

Then, later (i.e., now), you were again on `feature-branch`, but `git status` compared it to `origin/feature-branch`.  So this means that the upstream setting for `feature-branch` is now `origin/feature-branch`, as if you had run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature-branch feature-branch
```

I note that you mention:

> I made commits [on `feature-branch`] and pushed my local branch to remote ...

I am guessing, since you did *not* say this, that the *way* you did this was to run:

```
git push -u origin feature-branch
```

See the `-u` in there?  That tells `git push` that, if it successfully pushes `feature-branch` to `origin`, creating or updating `feature-branch` in that other Git to which you are pushing, then *your* Git should *change* the upstream for `feature-branch` to the corresponding `origin/feature-branch`, as if you had run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature-branch
```

You *could* set the upstream back to `origin/master`, but this is generally not a great idea.  Now that there's an `origin/feature-branch` that your Git is using to remember where `feature-branch` is on `origin`, it's better to compare your own `feature-branch` to the one on `origin`.  This is because now that you have *published* your commits, other people who are also using the other Git at `origin` may have picked them up.  Moreover, as [Viktor Seč mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43507855/1256452), that sets your default upstream for `git merge` and `git rebase` (these being the second half of what `git pull` runs).

If you want to compare your `feature-branch` to your own `master` just briefly and temporarily, consider running the commands:

```
git log --oneline master..feature-branch
```

or:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

(which lets you view *all* your branches and remote-tracking branches, all at once, with some graphics to help you relate the commits).

Answer (score 2):

This depends on `upstream`. You can set upstream (server) branch for your local branch with

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/BRANCH
```

This also sets the default target for your `git push` and `git pull`.

I don't think you should want to set local feature branch to track a remote master, though.

Answer (score 0):

For your work around, **it’s mainly caused you set `origin/master` as tracking branch for `feature-branch` at first, and then change the tracking branch as `origin/feature_branch`**. Steps may set/change the tracking branch:

1. Create `feature-branch` by `git checkout -b feature_branch origin/master`.
2. You can check the tracking branches relationship with local branches by `git branch -vv`. The tracking branch for `feature_branch` is `origin/master` at first.
3. After you made changes in `feature_branch` and push it to remote by `git push -u origin feature_branch`.
4. Now you change the tracking branch for `feature_branch` as `origin/feature_branch`. You can check by `git branch -vv`.